# Windows 8 recursive directory tree give stack overflow when trying to delete

Tags: windows, recursion, directory, overflow

...\Google\Desktop\Install exploit has left a (Win8) directory with DI attributes and a recursive directory structure. I cannot find a way to remove the attributes or delete the tree.
I have "removed" the file by renaming, moving, reowning and setting NO access to anyone (in safe mode).
Any attempts at deleting doesn't work as any delete command crashes with a stack overflow as the directory tree is recursive (in two layers of blank sub-directory names).

Answer (score 0):

Deletion of files/folders was possible using DOS naming convention (DIR /x) after allowing access.